# R Shiny - Detect whether a slider or radio button was used

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny script with a number of radio buttons and sliders. How do I detect whether a user clicked a radio button OR a slider. I don't care which specific slider or radio button.

Here's a simple example with comments.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("slider vs radio button"),

  sidebarPanel(

    sliderInput("a", 
                label = "Select an input to display",
                min = 0, max = 100, value = 50),

    radioButtons("detail", "Detail",
                 choiceNames = list(
                   "Low",
                   "Medium",
                   "High"
                 ),
                 choiceValues = list(
                   "1", "8", "12"
                 ), inline = TRUE, selected = "8")
  ),

  mainPanel(h1(textOutput("text")))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderText({
    paste(input$a, ",", input$detail)
  })
  # If user moved slider say "slider" 
  # If user clicked radio button say "radio"
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server code below illustrates two cases:
- how to use observers for individual inputs
- how to combine two inputs into a new reactive value

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$text <- renderText({
        paste(input$a, ",", input$detail)
    })

    rv <- reactiveValues(
        clicked = NULL
    )

    # If user moved slider say "slider" 
    observeEvent({
        input$a
        # add other sliders here
    }, {
        cat("individual: slider\n")
        rv$clicked <- NULL  # reset if previous "slider"
        rv$clicked <- "slider"
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE) 

    # If user clicked radio button say "radio"
    observeEvent(input$detail, {
        cat("individual: radio\n")
        rv$clicked <- NULL  # reset if previous "radio"
        rv$clicked <- "radio"
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE) 

    observeEvent(rv$clicked, {
        cat("combined:", rv$clicked, "\n")
    })
}
```

Comment: OK Thanks Mike. Quick question. I'm not familiar with the structure function({...}, {...} as you did with your first observeEvent. Can you explain that a bit?

Comment: It's `observeEvent` specific. If you look at the [help](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/observeEvent.html), the first argument `eventExpr` can be any expression (if we use `{`) and it can include several reactives, e.g. `{input$a input$b}` - it does not do anything, just triggers the observer when `a` or `b` (or both) change. The second `{...}` you are already familiar, you used it for `output$text` and it is shown in the help examples.